# Determine Offset and Page Address from Logical Address

Tags: memory, paging, offset, memory-address

I've got two addresses: 20000 and 60000, I should calculate the offset and the page knowing that the pages are 8KB big. Shouldn't it be impossible?

Comment: No, it's simple arithmetic. Why do you think it would be impossible?

Answer (score 0):

- **Page** = *address* div 8192
- **Offset** = *address* mod 8192